# django storages uploades to amazon s3 but displays error when accessed from the website

Tags: django, amazon-s3, boto, boto3, django-storage

I have a single page application which use Vuejs and django as its backend. I am using django-storages and boto3 to store files. I have install aws cli and has set up credentials. Also in my project settings these are added:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'mybucket-name-static'
DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'storages.backends.s3boto3.S3Boto3Storage'
```

I can run `collectstatic` and it does upload to my bucket. However, no static files are downloaded into the browser. If I inspect the url of the static files in the website, extra strings are attached to the urls, and opening those urls displays an error msg:

```
<Error>
    <script id="tinyhippos-injected"/>
    <Code>PermanentRedirect</Code>
    <Message>
        The bucket you are attempting to access must be addressed using the specified endpoint. Please send all future requests to this endpoint.
    </Message>
    <Bucket>mybucket-name-static</Bucket>
    <Endpoint>mybucket-name-static.s3.amazonaws.com</Endpoint>
    <RequestId>xdxdxxdxd</RequestId>
    <HostId>
        YmH2sBIsddvdrdSxrp8viWZBIoZFlfqUpp6YGJHgVkMH2Vh4AOZP9xeUoezJI0Y=
    </HostId>
</Error>
```

index.html:

```
{% load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="{% static "favicons/favicon.ico" %}" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="icon" href="{% static "favicons/favicon.ico" %}" type="image/x-icon">
    <title>app</title>
    <link href="{% static "css/app.7759951d6d7e8ca6b5f586cdd9b55f3b.css" %}" rel=stylesheet>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>

    <script type="application/javascript" src="{% static "js/manifest.862a9db37e07dc2a85b7.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="{% static "js/vendor.09e075a2fb63be36f883.js" %}"></script>
    <script type="application/javascript" src="{% static "js/app.f6fac1f9f25fe4014887.js" %}"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Could you please help me out. What am I missing here?

Comment: What's the value of your ``STATIC_URL`` setting and do you upload your static files to the root of the bucket?

You might want to check out this guide: https://blog.bitlabstudio.com/ultra-short-guide-to-django-and-amazon-s3-2c5aae805ce4

Comment: @TobiasLorenz I have updated my question with `STATIC_URL`. And yes, its inside the root of the bucket.